# How to parse only specific sheets in a workbook using openpyxl - or how to ignore empty sheets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

Well, this is actually a workaround for my main problem which is to "ignore the empty sheets in my workbook". I have found a way to print only those sheet names that are not empty. So, now I want to pass these names to my workbook and access only those sheets instead of every single sheet in `wb`. (I need to use `openpyxl` for this.)

I'm trying the below but it doesn't work:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("source_file.xlsx", data_only=TRUE)

for ws in wb.get_sheet_by_name(['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet4', 'Sheet5']):
 for row in ws:
   <do the necessary parsing operations here>
```

But this throws the below error:
`"Worksheet ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet4', 'Sheet5'] does not exist."`

And if I pass the names separately, then it says:

`TypeError: get_sheet_by_name() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given`

Is there a way that I can tell it to access only specific sheets instead of every sheet in `wb`? Or better, is it possible to ignore all the empty sheets while parsing a `.xlsx` workbook?

Comment: What version of `openpyxl` are you using? `get_sheets_by_name` isn't in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.get_sheet_by_name).

Comment: Please use the library methods correctly.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo: 'sheet' instead of 'sheets'. Corrected it just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the sheet names in a list, and then iterate over that list to open each sheet:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("source_file.xlsx", data_only=True)

sheets = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet4', 'Sheet5']

for sheet in sheets:
    for row in wb[sheet]:
       # <do the necessary parsing operations here>
```

Note that you can simply access a sheet from the workbook `wb` with `wb[sheetname]`. `get_sheet_by_name()` is deprecated. See the [official documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.get_sheet_by_name).